# open file with particular application where spaces in application name

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to open ex1.py in the terminal. If I just go:

open ex1.py the file opens in textwrangler.

But I want to use sublime. So I tried this:

```
open -a SublimeText ex1.py
Unable to find application named 'SublimeText'

open -a Sublime Text 2 ex1.p
The files /Users/macuser/Documents/pyleo/Text and /Users/macuser/Documents/pyleo/2 do not exist.
```

When I control click sublime > show in finder the name is "Sublime Text 2". Presumably the spaces are causing an issue.

How can I open ex1.py in Sublime text 2 using the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the application name in single quotes:

```
open -a 'Sublime Text 2' ex1.py
```